# Custom order in DataTables (jQuery plug-in)

Tags: datatables

Each row in my dataset has an unique identifier. I want them to be ordered by my own custom order sequence. Here's an example:

I have my raw data:

```
ID Name
-------
1 Peter
2 John
3 Steve
```

And my order sequence, e.g. 3,1,2.

When I initialize the DataTable I want my entries to show up like this (according to my pre-computed order sequence):

```
ID Name
-------
3 Steve
1 Peter
2 John
```

Comment: How do you get/calculate your custom order sequence?

Comment: I get the raw table data and the custom order sequence and have to create the table with this sequence. So it doesn't really matter where I get the sequence from.

Comment: It matters, because you could be facing [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/306278), where you ask for your **attempted solution** but the actual solution could be different. Can you post some HTML/JS code illustrating the format of your custom order sequence and your table data (it could be sourced from HTML or Ajax or JavaScript)?

Comment: edit ---------- gonna setup an example

Comment: Thanks for posting the example. I think there is simple solution but do you need to have order in URL or just want the order to be preserved? Also I assume you don't want the first table to be sortable at all, right?

Comment: I want the table to be sortable using the reorder plugin etc, and the sorting has to change the URL hash (using some callbacks I guess). But this is something I'll look into after I've resolved this problem. The first thing I would like to archive is the sorting after reloading the page. So if I open index.html#3;2;6 I want them to be sorted 3, 2, 6 in the sticky-table. And if I access index.html#4;3;5 I want them to be sorted 4,3,5 and so on. There has to be an easy way to get this done. Thank you for looking into this/helping by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work just fine. There were couple issues though.

- RowReorder plugin requires order column in order to work correctly.
- You need to handle [reorder event](http://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html) [`row-reorder`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/row-reorder) and change your URL hash accordingly.
- Sorting on the top table needs to be disabled unless you want to handle [`order`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/order) event and adjust URL hash accordingly.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xhpfqoL/8/) for code and demonstration.